# iSCSI issue; "the media is write protected"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, storage-area-network, iscsi, synergy

i've got some serious issues with w2k8 r2 standard and iSCSI controller. i'm running dell server, connected via ethernet to synergy NAS, which is handling LUN via iSCSI. i'm using ms iSCSI initiator to mount it, and it's working like a charm but my LUN's are write protected!

i've already managed to check ACL permisions, sharing permisions, user/group permisions etc. i've also cleared write protection from disk with diskpart using ATTR DISK CLEAR READONLY ( it was mentioned as common problem)

dump from diskpart:

```
DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
```

that issue is related to all luns on synergy NAS. i'm not using any encryption/authentication cos my intranet is not connected to internet. all of them are 1,99TB, if it is important.

Comment: Have you tried the diskpart command `attributes disk clear readonly`?

Comment: "i've also cleared write protection from disk with diskpart using ATTR DISK CLEAR READONLY ( it was mentioned as common problem)"

Comment: DOH! :) I completely missed that.

Comment: Do you see any events in the Windows event logs?

Comment: virtual disk service is not related, am i right? : D

only "information" events, like that
[link](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH146531)

Comment: PLEASE HELP, STILL NO SOLUTION

Comment: fixed by deleting LUNS and setting them up again -.-